# How the regex substitution is working in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have tried the remove duplicates from the strings,  `"a","b","b","a","c"` after removing the result is `"a","b","c",`. I have achieved this, but I have a doubt about working of regex substitution

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my $s = q+"a","b","b","a","c"+;

 $s=~s/ ("\w"),? / ($s=~s|($1)||g)?"$1,":"" /xge;
#^                   ^
#|                   Consider this as s2
#Consider this as s1

print "\n$s\n\n";
```

`s1` value contain string as `"a","b","b","a","c"`

Step 1

After substitution:

Guess, what is the data contain `s1` variable from the following `"a","b","b","c"` or `"a","b","b","a","c"` or `,"b","b",,"c"` data.?

I have run the regex with eval grouping

```
$s=~s/ ("\w"),? (?{print "$s\n"})/ ($s=~s|($1)||g)?"$1,":"" /xge;
```

The result is

```
"a","b","b","a","c"
,"b","b",,"c"  #This is from after substitution
,,,,"c"
,,,,"c"
,,,,"c"
```

Now my dobut is `s2` variable also `$s` why it is not concatenated with `s1`, it  means at the second step the result should be `"a","b","b","c"` (All the string `"a"` is replaced with empty and `a` is added in the `$s`).?

---

**Edited**

The result from the eval grouping is `(?{print $s})`

```
"a","b","b","a","c"
,"b","b",,"c" 
,,,,"c"
,,,,"c"
,,,,"c"
```

After the substitution line I printed the `$s` variable it is giving `"a","b","c"`, How this output is coming.?

Comment: It's pretty hard to inspect the regex and deduce what it's supposed to do, maybe split it multiline and add a comment for each block and maybe others will make an effort to invest some time in solving your question.

Comment: From my point of view, your problem comes from the spaces in your regex. If you try `$s=~ s/ ("\w"),? /_/g;
print "\nString after replacing \$1 with _ :  $s";`, you will notice that your string is unchanged, but if you remove the spaces, you will have `$s=~ s/("\w"),?/_/g;` and then `$1` will be susbtituted with `_`.

Comment: I think there is [some options](https://perldoc.perl.org/re.html#%27Debug%27-mode) in `re` module for debugging.

Comment: As interesting as it is to uncover the precise semantics of the `s` command with the `e` flag, this code is unreadable and I'd junk it in favour of a more readable approach.  The same thing applies for your initialization of `$s~`: this is very hard to understand, so it's better to use a form that is obvious to everybody.

Answer (score 6):

A regex is (in my opinion) the wrong tool to use here. I would

- `split` the string on commas
- remove duplicates from the list returned by `split`
- `join` the list back into a string

Like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $str = q["a","b","b","a","c"];

my %seen;

$str = join ',',
       grep { ! $seen{$_}++ }
       split /,/, $str;

say $str;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Before using regex,  I have tried with hashes but it results is, data are get shuffled, so I have moved towards regex. Now your answer solved my hash shuffling problem. But I'm eager to know how the regex substitution is working.

Answer (score 2):

The proper solution to this is split, filter, rejoin as @Dave Cross has already demonstrated.

...

However, the following regex solution does work and hopefully demonstrates why Dave's solution is superior

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = q{"a","b","b","a","c"};

1 while $str =~ s{
    \A
    (?: (?&element) , )*
    ( (?&element) )           # Capture in \1
    (?: , (?&element) )*
    \K
    ,
    \1                        # Remove the duplicate along with preceding comma
    (?= \z | , )

    (?(DEFINE)
        (?<element>
            "
            \w
            "
        )
    )
}{}xg;

say $str;
```

Outputs:

```
"a","b","c"
```